# Getting button's attribute with jquery to call a Controler with attributes

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, twitter-bootstrap

I'm trying to call a controller and passing it the value of a  button attribute. Somehow tis is not working .

==========button=============================

```
<td class="pdsa-areas-button-column">
    <a data-pdsa-val="@item.Id"
    class="btn btn-default btn-sm">
    <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-th-list"></i>
    </a>
</td>
```

=============================script=============

```
$(".pdsa-areas-button-column").on("click", function (e) {
                e.preventDefault();

                var id3 = $(this).data('data-pdsa-val');
                window.location.href = '@Url.Action("Index", "Area", new { testId = "id3"})';

            });
```

Also tried   var id3 = $(this).attr('data-pdsa-val'); with no luck.

What is wrong with this code?
Thanks

Comment: You need to bind event with `anchor`

Comment: Also you only need `...data('pdsa-val')`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use this

```
$(".pdsa-areas-button-column").on("click", function (e) {
                e.preventDefault();
                 var obj = $(this).find('a').data();
                var id3 = obj.pdsaVal
                window.location.href = '@Url.Action("Index", "Area", new { testId = "id3"})';

            });
```

Comment: Don't use `.attr('data-pdsa-val')`, use `.data('pdsa-val')`

Comment: Because that's what it was designed for! And OP is already using the `data` function.

Comment: @Jay: Thanks so much. That solved the issue. However there should be something wrong on line                                                                        window.location.href = '@Url.Action("Index", "Area", new { testId = "id3"})';

Comment: for id3=45 , what is sent is  http://localhost/Area/Index/id3 instead of http://localhost/Area/Index/45 ...

Comment: oh yes. i just focus on  var  id3 so i will forgot to change window.location.href @DavidT.